# 'ENTER' Key brings error in python when input asks for integer

Tags: python, task, enter

I'm working on a template for a menu system and I have it sorted out quite well for a beginner.  I've had some good help through stackoverflow in the past few days and figured I'd ask what's wrong here.

Here's the Code:

```
# Multitasker
# Allows User to Pick an Item that is Defined.

# This is the initial screen.

print("""
            XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
            X                                        X
            X            DEMO MULTITASK DEMO         X
            X                                        X
            XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
            X                                        X
            X               MULTITASKING             X
            X           --------------------         X
            X             MAIN MENU SYSTEM           X
            X            FOR GAME PLATFORMS          X
            X           --------------------         X
            X                                        X
            XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX

                     PRESS 'ENTER' TO CONTINUE""",end=" ")

# Input used to prevent the Multitask Selector Menu from Appearing at First!
input(" ")

# Defining Task 1 
def task1():
    print("""
            XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
            X    YOU HAVE CHOSEN TO DISPLAY TASK 1   X
            XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
            """, end=" ")

# Defining Task 2
def task2():
    print("""
            XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
            X    YOU HAVE CHOSEN TO DISPLAY TASK 2   X
            XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
            """, end=" ")

# Defining Task 3
def task3():
    print("""
            XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
            X    YOU HAVE CHOSEN TO DISPLAY TASK 3   X
            XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
            """, end=" ")

# Defining Task 4
def task4():
    print("""
            XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
            X    YOU HAVE CHOSEN TO DISPLAY TASK 4   X
            XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
            """, end=" ")

# If the Player Selected an innappropriate task number greater than 4, this will   display.
def notatask():
    print("""
            XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
            X     THAT IS NOT A POSSIBLE CHOICE.     X
            XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
            """, end=" ")


# Starts choice off as having no selection.
choice = None
playername = " "

# While the variable 'choice' is not '0', it will continue to display the menu below
while choice != "0":
    print(
        """
            XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
            X                                        X
            X            MULTITASK SELECTION         X
            X                                        X
            XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
            X                                        X
            X                0 - Quit                X
            X                1 - Task 1              X
            X                2 - Task 2              X
            X                3 - Task 3              X
            X                4 - Task 4              X
            X                                        X
            XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
            """, end=" ")

    choice = int(input("\n\t\tPick a Task Between 0-4:\t#"))
    print()

    # Exit
    if choice == int('0'):
        print("""
            XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
            X                                        X
            X            DEMO MULTITASK DEMO         X
            X                                        X
            XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
            X                                        X
            X               MULTITASKING             X
            X           --------------------         X
            X             MAIN MENU SYSTEM           X
            X            FOR GAME PLATFORMS          X
            X           --------------------         X
            X                                        X
            XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
            """, end="")
        print("\t\t", playername, end="")
        print("""
                    PRESS 'ENTER' TO CONTINUE""", end=" ")
        input(" ")

    # Task 1
    elif choice == int('1'):
        task1()

    # Task 2
    elif choice == int('2'):
        task2()

    # Task 3
    elif choice == int('3'):
        task3()

    # Task 4
    elif choice == int('4'):
        task4()

    # Not a Correct Selection
    elif choice > int('4'):
        notatask()

    # Enter Key
    elif choice == ('ENTER'):
        notatask()
```

So, what I don't understand is what I need to do to make it call notatask() when someone hits a key other than 0, 1, 2, 3, or 4.

Can anybody lead me in the right direction?

Thanks in Advance.

Best,

Steven

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After the `elif` for Task 4, just use an `else`.

```
# Task 4
elif choice == int('4'):
    task4()

# Everything else
else:
    notatask()
```

Comment: Thanks for the response - this is what I get - Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "N:\multitasker.py", line 89, in <module>
    choice = int(input("\n\t\tPick a Task Between 0-4:\t#"))
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''

Comment: Ah, right, you're trying to make an integer out of an enter. Don't try to convert the input to int then. Remove the int() from the line `choice = int(input("\n\t\tPick a Task Between 0-4:\t#"))`, and also from all the `elif choice == int(...)` lines. That should get rid of that error.

Comment: aggh, I had to remove the int() from choice = int(input("\n\t\tPick a Task Between 0-4:\t#"))  - Thanks!

Comment: hmm, now that removes my ability to re-enter into the multitask selection if I type '0'.  Before, If I hit '0', it would return to the 'DEMO MULTITASK DEMO' screen and I'd hit enter and it would show the multitask selection menu again...hmmm.

Comment: aggh, what I did was made choice = None after showing the demo screen again.

Answer (score 1):

Don't call `int()` immediately.  Check the value first.  Like this:

```
choice = input("\n\t\tPick a Task Between 0-4:\t#")
if not choice:
    notatask()
    continue
choice = int(choice)
```